# file_get_contents and variable echo

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to figure this out, I want to echo information from a variable or any php code beside `'http://vine.co/v/'` under `line 3` can anyone help me?

My code:

```
<?php

$vine = file_get_contents('http://vine.co/v/', false, $test);
$test = "haiKqBFA9Yw";
preg_match('/property="og:image" content="(.*?)"/', $vine, $matches);
$url = $matches[1];
$url = str_replace( 'https://', 'http://', $url );
$url = str_replace( 'versionId=', '', $url );
$img = $url;
$url = substr($img, 0, strpos($img, "?"));
echo $url;
```

it just returns with `$test` not a defined variable.

Comment: According to docs, third parameter in `file_get_contents`, needs to be a resource. Check 4th example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Alright, Thank-You for the help. For those who down voted this i'm still new to php and I did research this quite a bit just need help with understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't parse HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/67332)

Simple function that returns all open graph metas from given url:

```
function getUrlOpenGraphMetas($url) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $metas = array();
    if (!$entries = $xpath->query('//html/head/meta[starts-with(@property, "og:")]')) return $metas;
    foreach ($entries as $entry) $metas[$entry->getAttribute('property')] = $entry->getAttribute('content');
    return $metas;
}
```

Use:

```
$metas = getUrlOpenGraphMetas('https://vine.co/v/haiKqBFA9Yw');
$img = $metas['og:image'];
if (($pos = strpos($img, '?')) !== false) $img = substr($img, 0, $pos);
$img = str_replace('https://', '//', $img);
echo $img;
```

Comment: Thank-You for the response Glavic, However when I inserted your code it returned with this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\UwAmp\www\tos.php on line 4`

Comment: Sorry, PHP>=5.4 syntax ;) I changed array from `[]` to `array()`. Try now.

Comment: Ah Sorry, I didn't see your updated code. You're my hero haha. Thankyou for the help :3